# ThreeJS web app shows whitescreen after being deployed

Tags: javascript, three.js, hosting

ive been trying to deploy a threejs project that im working on, on either github pages or firebase, but whenever I deploy them, the browser just shows a whitescreen, its weird because when I run the same project through localhost, everything its working perfectly.

here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Waber App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="bg"></canvas>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my main.js

```
import "./style.css";

import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: document.querySelector("#bg"),
});

renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
camera.position.setZ(30);

renderer.render(scene, camera);

const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(10, 3, 16, 100);

const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0xff6347,
});
const   torus = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

//scene.add(torus);

const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
pointLight.position.set(20, 20, 20);

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight();

scene.add(pointLight, ambientLight);

const lightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(pointLight);
const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(200, 50);
//scene.add(lightHelper, gridHelper);

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

function addStar() {
  const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 24, 24);
  const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
  const star = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  const [x, y, z] = Array(3)
    .fill()
    .map(() => THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(100));
  star.position.set(x, y, z);
  scene.add(star);
}

Array(200).fill().forEach(addStar);

const spaceTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("space.jpeg");
scene.background = spaceTexture;

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  moon.rotation.y += 0.005;

  torus.rotation.x += 0.01;
  torus.rotation.y += 0.005;
  torus.rotation.z += 0.01;
  controls.update();

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

const moonTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("moon.jpeg")
const normalTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("normal.jpeg")

const moon = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry(3,32,32),
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    map: moonTexture,
    normalMap: normalTexture,
  })
)
scene.add(moon)


animate();
```

[LOCALHOST PREVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a9eC.png)

[FIREBASE PREVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHsCu.png)

Comment: We need more info. Are there any console errors? Do you have a link to the deployed version? Are all your scripts and assets loading successfully?

Comment: Im sorry yes, here are 2 links: [githubpages](https://waberhoruhe.github.io/ThreeJS/) _italic_ and [firebase](https://threejs-2fea3.web.app/) _italic_

Comment: Change the path to your main.js from /main.js to ./main.js

Comment: changed my path already and im getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."

Comment: This needs more information. When you bring up the developer tools in your web browser on the live site, what do you see?  Are there errors in the console?  Are there failed resource downloads in the network tab?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've found a solution for your problem yet, but I had the same problem a couple of days ago. I was able to solve it and deploy on Github Pages by putting all my javascript code into my index.html file. I added the link to my CSS file somewhere in the head of the html like you normally would:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
```

Then I added the Threejs cdn and all my js code at the bottom of the body. So yours would have to look something like this:

```
<canvas id="bg"></canvas> 
<script type="module">
      // Find the latest version by visiting https://unpkg.com/three. The URL will
      // redirect to the newest stable release.
      import * as THREE from "https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js";
      import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
      
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

//Followed by all the rest of your code.

      

     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what worked for me, anyway.

I hope you find this helpful!

Full disclosure, this is my first time answering someone's question on here. If you need anymore info, let me know, and I'll do my best to supply it.